# Replace cv::resize() with Intel Integrated Performance Primitives (IPP) resize?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, image-resizing, intel-ipp

I'm trying to improve [`surf.cpp`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/xfeatures2d/src/surf.cpp) parallel performance, and according to my analysis, a lot of time is spent at line 697:

```
// Scale the window to size PATCH_SZ so each pixel's size is s. This
// makes calculating the gradients with wavelets of size 2s easy
resize(win, _patch, _patch.size(), 0, 0, INTER_AREA);
```

Where `Mat win(win_size, win_size, CV_8U, winbuf);`

I never used [Intel Integrated Perfomance Primitives](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-ipp) (IPP), but from my understanding usually has better performance than OpenCV. I've seen [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/504353) that you can use it to resize an image, what is the equivalent command above using IPP?

Comment: did you compile openCV with IPP?

Comment: I think I did using the version provided by opencv itself

Comment: compile it yourself with IPP support! It will probably give you a nice speedup.

Comment: @Micka thanks for your answer, but by defualt will use its own provided version of IPP, right? In that case I'm already using IPP and the `cv::resize` function seems inefficient! Besides, how do I understand if `cv::resize` is implemented using IPP?

Comment: no, default doesn't use IPP, because it has different license or sth.

Comment: with getBuildInformation() you can print the compilation stuff used in your library. http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/utility_and_system_functions_and_macros.html#const%20std%3a%3astring&%20getBuildInformation%28%29

Comment: @Micka you're the most expert guy that I know about OpenCV here, **please** could you help me [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43759869/is-there-any-opencv-or-ipp-equivalent-for-this-function)? I'm struggling